# Suppress REST Logging Calls from Supertest

Tags: mocha.js, supertest, should.js

I have started using MEAN stack and currently writing REST unit tests using Super Test

I want to have a little bit more clarity in my log file so that I can easily see my successful and failed tests.

I wish to suppress the console output for the actual rest API call which I think are coming out of SuperTest.

This image shows the logs I want to suppress.

[image: Suppress Super Test Logging]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it's actually coming from expressjs/morgan.  I've gotten around it by setting the env to test and disabling morgan for the test env.

In my test files:

`process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';`

In app.js:

`if(app.get('env') !== 'test') app.use(logger('dev'));`

Answer (score 0):

You can setup morgan to accept a skip function.

Then, you can, say, toggle an env variable on/off - or define skipping logic of your own to temporarily mute the logging.

```
app.use(
  logger('dev', {
    skip: function(req, res) {
      return process.env.MUTE_LOGGER === 'on';
    },
  }),
);
```